# Communication links failure in docker, SpringBoot, Mysql and tomcat

Tags: mysql, spring, docker, tomcat

I'm trying to run an image on docker to execute my web app, but It says that I have communication links failure error, and I don't know how to solve it although other users had this issue.
My .properties is:

```
#logging
logging.level.root=info
logging.file.name=application.org

#port
server.port=8095
#server.servlet.context-path=/proyecto
#spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
#spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
#spring.web.resources.static-locations=classpath:/static/

#database
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://backend:3307/proyectodiagrama     #cambiar a localhost 
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=

# Swagger Documentacion
spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy=ANT_PATH_MATCHER
spring.mvc.hiddenmethod.filter.enabled=true

#crear tablas la primera vez:
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
#debugSql
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

#seguridad
spring.security.user.name=usuario 
spring.security.user.password=pass
```

My Dockerfile is:

```
# docker build -t mywebapp .

FROM tomcat:9.0

RUN cp -r webapps.dist/manager webapps/manager

ADD proyecto.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/

VOLUME /usr/local/tomcat/

EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]


# docker run -p 8080:8080 mywebapp
```

And my docker compose is:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
    db:
        image: mysql:5.7
        volumes:
            - /opt/test:/var/lib/mysql
            - ./mysql-dump:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
            MYSQL_DATABASE: proyectodiagrama
            MYSQL_USER: 
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: 
        ports:
            - 3306:3306
    web:
        depends_on:
            - db
        image: tomcat
        volumes:
            - ./target/proyecto.war:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/proyecto.war
        ports:
        - '8080:8080'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
            MYSQL_DATABASE: proyectodiagrama
            MYSQL_USER: 
            MYSQL_PASSWORD:
            SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://backend:3307/database?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
```

Then, I execute `docker-compose up`, and `docker run -p 8080:8080 mywebapp .` but It throws the following lines:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.3)

2023-04-26 09:38:14.930  INFO 1 --- [           main] principal.SpringBootInitializer          : Starting SpringBootInitializer v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 17.0.6 on 2b19457b74b6 with PID 1 (/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/proyecto/WEB-INF/classes started by root in /usr/local/tomcat)
2023-04-26 09:38:14.932  INFO 1 --- [           main] principal.SpringBootInitializer          : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-04-26 09:38:15.561  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-04-26 09:38:15.602  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 32 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-04-26 09:38:15.885  INFO 1 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 889 ms
2023-04-26 09:38:16.177  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-04-26 09:38:16.250  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.10.Final
2023-04-26 09:38:16.386  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2023-04-26 09:38:16.478  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-04-26 09:38:22.994 ERROR 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:828) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:448) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:241) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at
```

Comment: Your `spring.datasource.url` lists port 3307, but MySQL normally listens on port 3306.

Comment: @DavidMaze yeah, I use xampp and I have It configured on 3307

Comment: Your db service is named `db` not `backend` you need to use the service name to connect.

Comment: @M.Deinum changed it, but still doesnt work